# How can I do a hover only if a link does not have a class of "folder"?

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
<a class="folder"><span>Background</span></a>
```

and the following CSS:

```
        ul.arbo li > a:hover span,
        ul.arbo li > a.current span {
            background: #999999;
        }
```

How can I modify the CSS so it does NOT apply if the link has a class of folder. In other words so it will not apply for the above HTML

Comment: Is it a jQuery or a CSS question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do in css with negation pseudo-class selector [`:not`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) , as follows:

```
:not(.folder) {

}
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8r4GP/) (provided by insertusernamehere).

Comment: Thanks for beat me to provide a demo, will add to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 has the `:not()` selector, which you can add to your CSS (or you could do this with jQuery, either way). Mind you, this will only work in newer browsers.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

```
:not(.folder)
```

In your instance:

```
ul.arbo li > a:not(.folder):hover span,
ul.arbo li > a:not(.folder).current span { }
```

Comment: IE8 and earlier do not support the :not selector.

Comment: Please don't use w3schools as reference source, it's not very trusted, see http://w3fools.com/ instead try to link to more reputable sources like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs

Comment: Haha agreed, I hate w3schools, not sure why I used it. Just wanted to post a quick link

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript or jQuery for this, and you can do it without CSS3 too (which may be relevant depending on what browsers you plan on supporting).

Just add another rule to prevent the background from changing on certain elements, like this:

```
ul.arbo li > a.folder:hover span
{
    background: inherit;   
}
```

[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/6qSe4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
:not(.folder) {

}
```

Is a good solutions.Don't forget to check what browser do you want too work!

:not selector is a CSS3 selector and not all the browser support it...for example IE8 and earlier do not support the :not selector.